# How can there be a one Nirvash, not to mention two?

Tags: eureka-seven

At the end of the original series (*Psalm of the Planets Eureka Seven*),

> Nirvash left with some Scub Coral to prevent the [Limit of Questions](http://eurekaseven.wikia.com/wiki/Limit_of_Questions), so there shouldn't even be a Nirvash.

In the sequel, *Eureka Seven Astral Ocean*, both Renton and Eureka have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mentioned in *Eureka Seven AO* that this Nirvash (RA272, Mark I) was originally created by Renton (as a homage to the original Nirvash from *Eureka Seven,* "typeZERO.") for Eureka in the far future, and was named "Nirvash Neo."

This new Nirvash does not initially have an [Archetype](http://eurekaseven.wikia.com/wiki/Archetype).